# How to deploy a java application on tomcat and access it online

Tags: java, tomcat, hosting, web-deployment

I wanna deploy a java app on tomcat 9 to be accessible by typing an address like www.justanormalapp.stuff. Now I have a dedicated server machine on which i'm going to be installing tomcat and deploying the WAR app file but it can be only accessed locally through http://localhost:8080/myapp/ and I don't know how to make it accessible online.

I am not looking for some fancy domain name as anything free will do since the app is only going to be used for 3 - 6 months.

Comment: ip-address:8080/myapp should work. If not look into firewall issues

Answer (score 0):

If all your PCs are not in the same net, you have to create an VPN to allow external computers access to your server.

**So:**

> 1. [Create your VPN](https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/).
> 2. Configure VPN in the PCs where you want to access to your application
> 3. Use ip:port/myapp

This should be enough.